# How to use a function from imported module within a local function?

Tags: python, function, import, module, global

I have a python module `a.py`:

```
def fun ( c, d, e, f ):
    print ( c + d + e + f )
```

In my `main.py`:

```
from a import *

def fun1 ():
    c = 'hello '
    d = 'how '
    e = 'are '
    f = 'you?'
    fun (c, d, e, f)

fun1 ()
```

Why am i getting the error:

`NameError: global name 'fun' is not defined`

I also tried:

```
from a import *

def fun1 ():
    global fun
    c = 'hello '
    d = 'how '
    e = 'are '
    f = 'you?'
    fun (c, d, e, f)

fun1 ()
```

The error still remains.

Comment: Both files must be in the same directory。and create `__init__.py` in the directory

Comment: It sounds as if you are importing the wrong `a` module. What does `print(a.__file__)` tell you was imported? Did you restart Python to make sure you are using a cached module object instead?

Comment: @liansheng: there is zero evidence here that this is an issue with top-level vs. namespaced modules.

Comment: The modules are not in the same directory but i did 'sys.path.insert(0, "<path_to_module_a>" )'

Comment: In the `a.py` file put a `print('a.py is being imported')` statement just before the `def fun` line, then run `main.py`. Does the `print` display anything?

Comment: Instead of a star import ("from a import *") which is a very bad practice anyway, use a qualified import, ie `from a import fun`. Chances are you'll now get an `ImportError` "cannot import name fun", which would means the `a` module you're importing is not the one you expected. To debug this second problem, just import the module itself (`import a`), followed by a `print(a)` statement which should tell you from which exact file it's been imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the __init__.py wihtin the same folder where a.py located.

And if your main.py is not in the same folder, you need to append the dir of the folder where a.py located to your sys.path.

If the folder structure looks like this:

```
./a_folder/a.py
./a_floder/__init__.py
./main_folder/main.py
```

The code in main.py should be:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../a_floder/')
from a import *
```

If the folder structure looks like this:

```
./a.py
./__init__.py
./main.py
```

The code in main.py should be:

```
from a import *
```